# android.annotation.SuppressLint undefined

Tags: android

I am new to Android trying to use Linphone pluging in Android getting android.annotation.SuppressLint undefined  erorrs after importing this API.
 The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type TargetApi PlusApi.java
please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Either change your target API to 16 or import the lint jar as follows:
Move your cursor over "SuppressLint", which will be underlined in red. Select the fix option "Fix project setup". From the popup list select "add archive 'annotations.jar'. Have a happy day.